# Wrong screen resolution in Ubuntu (nvidia proprietary driver)

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, ubuntu-9.10, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a BenQ GW2400 and a Geforce FX5200. I run Ubuntu Karmic 9.10, and have the newest proprietary Nvidia driver installed. The GW2400 supports 1920x1200, but I can only select 1600x1200 from the nvidia x server program. Does anyone know how to enable higher resolutions? I've read something about adding custom modelines in /etc/X11/xorg.conf and so on, but I don't know if that applies to Karmic.

Thanks.

**Update**

I tried all of the approaches in the answers below, with no success. Everything got sorted out as soon as I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 (even fixed my half-broken WLAN connection). Anyways, thanks for answering guys :)

Answer (score 1):

First backup your `xorg.conf` file:

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

The default color depth is 24 I believe, so in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` add this:

```
Section "Screen"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1920x1200" "1600x1200" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

restart the X server for changes to take effect. You can use `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`.

This may also come in handy, [HOWTO: change resolution/refresh rate in Xorg](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=83973).

Comment: i believe stock ubuntu 9.10 doesn't actually provide an *xorg.conf* (or it's empty) -- it allows X to detect everything on startup.  you can *add* anything you need to one, so this is still the proper procedure, but i think you'll need to *add* the entire *Screen* section (that "Display" is a "SubSection" of).

Comment: Weird, they keep changing things on me! Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, and ctrl-alt-BackSpace doesn't work by default anymore either.

Comment: Oh gosh, fixed again :)

Comment: `sudo aptitude install dontzap` should reinstate the old Ctrl-Alt-Backspace behavior.  er... oops, n'mind, that's jaunty only: in karmic, see this to reenable via XKB: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/DontZap

Answer (score 0):

you can add the undetected resolution to the monitor by following these directions:

```
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution
```

then it will still be able to intelligently handle monitor changes etc.